# MySQL if statement sequence in stored function

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sequence, stored-functions

I have a peculiar problem using the IF statement in MYSQL.
I have a stored function that returns the content of a table as a string. For my string to return the correct number of results I prepare a select statement based on a number. if the number is <= 9 then one sql statement and above 9 another.

However, in the sequence I can only put the if statement at the end of my function. If I put it in the correct place, where it is currently commented out it gives me a syntax error. If I put the if statement at the end of the function incorrect place I do not receive the error.

Please help. I do not know if this is a bug or my own mistake.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `returnstring`(IDGrade int) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
Declare fSubjectID, sSubjectID varchar (255);
declare sqlstatement varchar(255);

#Declare variable for done of loop
Declare done int default 0;

#Declare variables from the select statement
#IF     IDGRADE <= 9 then set sqlstatement = 'SELECT subjectID FROM subjecttb where sectType = "b" or secttype = "j" order by subjectID';
#ELSEIF IDGRADE > 9  then set sqlstatement = 'SELECT subjectID FROM subjecttb where sectType = "b" or secttype = "s" order by subjectID';
#END IF; 


#Declare a cursor to iterate through the table
declare cursor1 cursor for 
        SELECT subjectID
        FROM `marksdb`.`subjecttb` 
        where sectType = 'b' or secttype = 'j' order by subjectID;

#Continue loop until nothing is found anymore
declare continue handler for not found set done=1;

#Runs the select statement
open cursor1;

#Declares a loop
set fsubjectid='';
SubjectID_loop:loop
    Fetch cursor1 into sSubjectID;
    if done=1 then # no more rows to fetch
          leave SubjectID_loop;
    end if;
    set fSubjectID = concat(fSubjectID, sSubjectID , ' varchar (255), ');
end loop SubjectID_loop;
set fSubjectID = substring(fSubjectID, 1, length(fsubjectid)-2);
close cursor1;

return fSubjectID;

#Declare variables from the select statement
IF IDGRADE <= 9 then set sqlstatement = 'SELECT subjectID FROM subjecttb where sectType = "b" or secttype = "j" order by subjectID';
ELSEIF IDGRADE > 9  then set sqlstatement = 'SELECT subjectID FROM subjecttb where sectType = "b" or secttype = "s" order by subjectID';
END IF;
```

END

Comment: Found the answer. Cursors may not be used after a selection type!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have in your code segment is the order of your statements. **You issue a SET statement before declaration statements**. Statements should be ordered as follows:

1. Variable and condition declarations.
2. Cursor declarations.
3. Handler declarations.
4. Program code.

Try ordering you function as described above and it should work. **Also don't forget to add END$$ to your function.**